# Why is Helen Magnus' Father Still Alive?

Tags: sanctuary

In Sanctuary, Helen Magnus appears to have stopped aging, even in the first few years of the series (to say nothing of what happened in Season 4).  But then her Father shows up and is in several episodes.  Yet there's no reference to him having had any connection with the Source Blood.

Why didn't he die at a "normal" age?  Will he not age, or is he aging extremely slowly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In season 1, episode 10 *Warriors*, he's revived because the Cabal is interested in what he knows. It is not explained exactly how, but according to Wikipedia, citing the audio commentary for the episode on the DVD:

> In writing "Warriors", Egan wanted to reintroduce Magnus' father Gregory Magnus from the webisodes; there were plans to introduce him in "Fata Morgana", but the idea did not make it to the final episode. Gregory was written not to have the longevity of his daughter. Egan decided not to include a full explanation of how he survived a hundred years without aging, but wanted to hint to the audience that he was in fact cryogenically frozen by the Cabal.

Presumably, then, he is aging at a normal rate and will die within a few decades.

Answer (score 4):

Later on in the series, there are a few more clues that pop up about Gregory Magnus's life.

- He gave Helen the two pieces to the Praxis map when she was in her 20s and 30s.  So he definitely knew of the city's existence at that time.
- He was well-known as a model citizen of Praxis.

  - Adam Worth was taken in openly, while Magnus and the rest of the Sanctuary team most definitely were not.  I doubt he could've become such a model citizen in just a year.
- Adam Worth was also still alive due to the advanced medicine of Praxis.

Gregory Magnus's long life is, like Adam Worth, due to having lived in Praxis for so long.  However, because this is a retcon of the originally implied cryo-freezing by the Cabal, it leaves a gap as to *why* he left Praxis in the first place.  The [Sanctuary wikia page](http://sanctuary.wikia.com/wiki/Gregory_Magnus) on him does say he left so he could make contact with Helen, when he was captured by the Cabal.  However, I don't recall that being in an episode myself.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. Okay then. Sorry didn't get that. Actually there is one possibility. Gregory could have taken some of the technology from praxis before It was destroyed and went into hiding and used it to help maintain his health.

Comment: This sounds possible, but it would be better if you provide some evidence for this theory.

Comment: Also, when responding to a comment, please click on the 'Add a comment' link beneath that comment, rather than using the 'Your Answer' field, which is only meant for posting answers to the question at the top of the thread.